# Incapsula module issue with XHR request

Tags: python, python-requests, incapsula

I am using the Incapsula module for Python, incombination with some proxy server shuffling to scrape data for personal use from a website.The module works to grab data from a web page, that I use to create the variable `my_header3`, which is used in the header in the code below.

However a blank string is returned when attempting to perform the same methodology to obtain data from an XHR request. Can anyone see from the below code what I need to change?

```
from incapsula import crack, IncapSession
import requests
from cookielib import LWPCookieJar
import json
import SelectProxy

SelectProxy.select_proxy()
local_proxy = SelectProxy.global_proxy

session = requests.Session()
session.proxies = {local_proxy}

url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/tournamentsfeed/12496/Fixtures/'

params = {'d': '201508',
'isAggregate': 'false'}

headers = {
'authority': 'www.whoscored.com',
'method': 'GET',
'path': '/tournamentsfeed/12496/Fixtures/?d=2015W08&isAggregate=false',
'scheme': 'https',
'accept': 'text/plain, */*; q=0.01',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6',
'model-last-mode': my_header3,
'referer': 'https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/England-Premier-League',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

response = session.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
print 'response = ', response
response = crack(session, response)
print 'response = ', response
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

my_header3 is grabbed using the below code. it is a part of the request header in the above code and I was not sure how else to generate this.

```
session = requests.Session()
session.proxies = {local_proxy}
cookies = LWPCookieJar('cookiejar')

url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/England-Premier-League'
headers = {
'authority': 'www.whoscored.com',
'method': 'GET',
'path': '/',
'scheme': 'https',
'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6',
'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
'referer': 'https://www.google.co.uk/',
'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'
}

response = session.get(url, headers=headers)  # url is blocked by incapsula
response = crack(session, response)  # url is no longer blocked by incapsula

regex = re.compile("'Model-Last-Mode': '.*?'", re.S)
my_header = re.search(regex, response.text)
my_header2 = my_header.group()

my_header3 = my_header2.replace("'Model-Last-Mode': '", '').replace("'", "")
print my_header3
```

Comment: What is the page url? Also what is `local_proxy`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham hellow again, long time no speak...the page URL is 'https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/England-Premier-League' and local_proxy is a variable generated by a function ive built which generates a list of proxy servers and picks one at random using the code 'SelectProxy.select_proxy()
local_proxy = SelectProxy.global_proxy'. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, why is it in a set  though? Also what is my_header3, running the code just using requests tells me the page does not exist

Comment: the XHR request relates to the calendar object for selecting match dates in the middle of the page

Comment: Ah ok, let me fire a request and see

Comment: i have edited the question to give the code showing how my_header3 is generated.

Comment: Is it the Premier-League fixtures date picker?

Comment: yes it is, that is correct.

Comment: I cannot use the one in the middle of the page using chrome and it is not there at all using firefox

Comment: the javascript item underneath the header 'Premier League Fixtures' I am talking about. I am using chrome to access it via web browser.

Comment: Yes, just having a look at what is happening.

Comment: I got it working then after two runs ended back at *The page you requested does not exist* so it seems they really don't want to be scraped.

Comment: i tried running the code you posted before you deleted it and it did not work for me at all. how could they be picking up that i am not going in via a web browser if i am using all the correct headers do you think?

Comment: Incapsula is proprietary software so I have no idea, I think scraping site using Ijncapsula is not going to be trivial, I will dig a bit deeper tomorrow when I get some free time and see of I can come up with anything

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. that would be appreciated. they brought this in a few months ago and i have only had chance to pick up trying to get round it recently.

Comment: i think i have it working!

Comment: i do have it working. the solution used bits of your original answer and bits of my question.

Comment: cool, what did you do to get it working?

Comment: Do you have an email address or anything? I will tell you how. Don't want to give it away on here!

Comment: have just mailed you now.

Comment: hmmmmm....was working last night, but now isnt...

Comment: actually have made a further amendment, which seems to have done the trick for now

Comment: I think scraping the site will be fragile, bots are something incapsula seem to be trying to keep out. I will have a look at your solution when I get back home.

Comment: Ok. I will email you the amendment shortly too

Comment: hey @gdogg371, I am also trying to do that but had not any luck so far. can you tell me how, please? I can write you my email.